# Is it possible to use NamedStyle inside of UserStyle with MAPSERVER SLD?

Tags: wms, mapserver, sld

I want to use a `NamedStyle` inside a `UserStyle` for the `ElseFilter` of my SLD-Definition:

```
<NamedLayer>
<Name>MyLayer</Name>
<UserStyle>
<FeatureTypeStyle>

<Rule>
<Name>Selected</Name>
<ogc:Filter>
<ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyName>my_id</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>31117</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
</ogc:Filter>
<PolygonSymbolizer>
<Fill>
<CssParameter name="fill">#008000</CssParameter>
</Fill>
<Stroke>
<CssParameter name="stroke">#BD0026</CssParameter>
<CssParameter name="width">30</CssParameter>
</Stroke>
</PolygonSymbolizer>
</Rule>

<Rule>
<Name>Others</Name>
<ElseFilter/>
<PolygonSymbolizer>
<Stroke>
<CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
</Stroke>
</PolygonSymbolizer>
</Rule>

</FeatureTypeStyle>
</UserStyle>

</NamedLayer>
```

Something like this:

```
<Rule>
<Name>Others</Name>
<ElseFilter/>
<NamedStyle>
    <Name>the_style</Name>
</NamedStyle>
</Rule>
```

Comment: what would that even mean? why do you want to do this?

Comment: I want only one feature to be drawn by userstyle and all other features should be displayed with Default style from the `mapfile`

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK [MapServer](http://mapserver.org/) doesn't use SLD internally, but will accept an SLD as part of a GetMap request, either by reference through an `SLD&` parameter or directly as the value of an `SLD_BODY&` parameter.

In any case MapServer supports the SLD standard, and allows for named styles, so it should be possible to add your style on top of the default style if required.

Comment: http://mapserver.org/ogc/sld.html#named-styles-support The named style works under `NamedLayers`, but it seems to be not valid inside of `UserStyles`. I want an `IF` - `ELSE` Statement, so that inside the if clause it should apply my userstyle and inside the else clause it should apply the default named style. Do you have any idea? Thanks